# Can you customize the position of Visual Studio status bar icons?

Tags: visual-studio

Can you move the Visual Studio status bar icons away from the bottom right position? I would like to have them somewhere where my eyes are more often during coding, e.g., as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot. The UI isn't particularly customizable, much to the chagrin of just about everyone, considering the way the VS team just loves to make superfluous changes.